# What is the most efficient way to store a bunch of empty fields, and ones with only a few choices?

Tags: mysql, storage

When I say efficient, I mean total storage(kb), and not excessively burdening the CPU.

I have 70 columns of data.  The last 35 fields have always been NULL.

- The table has only 4 columns of completely unique data.
- The rest of the fields have only few values.
- One fields has only GET,POST and their are 4-5 other values that never occur.
- The columns are 69 varchar, bigint,int, and 2 blob.(I am open to change)
  The blobs are text, but contain too many different characters set, or random junk from hackers.  So rather than figuring it out, binary and done.
- Most of the other columns have 4-5 distinct() values per column

  1. At what point does a lookup column make sense? 
     Another table with ID Value, and only the ID is present in the first table.  For example if you have GET,POST by the time you add overhead for lookup does it make sense to even do this.

     Should I use an enum or etc?

     The table will eventually hold 100,000+ rows.

     How many bytes in the value fields to actually save space before the whole lookup makes sense?

     What is the best way to handle the 35 blank columns in terms of storage?
     Create a separate table with a single ID, have the 35 columns with 1 row that has all NULL.  Then just say ID 1, and if a different arrangement ever comes along then it is ID 2?

  One column is always "Apache", another "keep-alive","closed",NULL.
  Encoding is "gzip, deflate, sdch","identity, gzip, deflate","deflate, gzip","gzip,deflate,br","gzip,deflate","gzip, deflate, sdch, identity","gzip","identity",NULL,"x-gzip, gzip, deflate","gzip","deflate"

Answering questions:

1. How is that table used?

   backend to apache via php. I will be looking for patterns, and marking them with a score indicating bad to good probability.
2. How do you query the database?

   Mainly via php(prepare), probably put a web gui on it.
3. When you perform queries that use this table: Do you need all the values for all the columns?

   No, certainly not the 35 blank columns.

   9 of the columns always have the same 1 record, and I will only care if they are different.  Maybe I will setup up a trigger, if they are ever different, but probably otherwise ignore those columns.

   So 70 -35 -9 = 26 or less frequently queried columns.

> ```
> Column    Type    Comment
> REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID    varchar(50) NULL     
> REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD   varchar(20) NULL     
> REDIRECT_STATUS   int(11) NULL     
> UNIQUE_ID varchar(50) NULL     
> HTTP_HOST varchar(30) NULL     
> HTTP_USER_AGENT   varchar(300) NULL    
> HTTP_ACCEPT   varchar(300) NULL    
> HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE  varchar(120) NULL    
> HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING  varchar(60) NULL     
> HTTP_COOKIE   blob NULL    
> HTTP_CONNECTION   varchar(30) NULL     
> HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS    varchar(10) NULL     
> HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL    varchar(50) NULL     
> PATH  varchar(300) NULL    
> SERVER_SIGNATURE  varchar(300) NULL    
> SERVER_SOFTWARE   varchar(20) NULL     
> SERVER_NAME   varchar(50) NULL     
> SERVER_ADDR   varchar(30) NULL     
> SERVER_PORT   varchar(5) NULL  
> REMOTE_ADDR   bigint(40) NULL  
> DOCUMENT_ROOT varchar(20) NULL     
> REQUEST_SCHEME    varchar(20) NULL     
> CONTEXT_PREFIX    varchar(300) NULL    
> CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT varchar(50) NULL     
> SERVER_ADMIN  varchar(40) NULL     
> SCRIPT_FILENAME   varchar(110) NULL    
> REMOTE_PORT   int(11) NULL     
> REDIRECT_URL  blob NULL    
> GATEWAY_INTERFACE varchar(15) NULL     
> SERVER_PROTOCOL   varchar(170) NULL    
> REQUEST_METHOD    varchar(20) NULL     
> QUERY_STRING  varchar(123) NULL    
> REQUEST_URI   blob NULL    
> SCRIPT_NAME   varchar(100) NULL    
> PHP_SELF  varchar(75) NULL     
> REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT    decimal(15,4) NULL   
> REQUEST_TIME  int(15) unsigned NULL    
> HTTP_PRAGMA   varchar(300) NULL    
> LESSKEY   varchar(300) NULL    
> NNTPSERVER    varchar(300) NULL    
> MANPATH   varchar(300) NULL    
> XDG_SESSION_ID    varchar(300) NULL    
> HOSTNAME  varchar(300) NULL    
> XKEYSYMDB varchar(300) NULL    
> HOST  varchar(300) NULL    
> TERM  varchar(300) NULL    
> SHELL varchar(300) NULL    
> PROFILEREAD   varchar(300) NULL    
> HISTSIZE  varchar(300) NULL    
> SSH_CLIENT    varchar(300) NULL    
> MORE  varchar(300) NULL    
> SSH_TTY   varchar(300) NULL    
> USER  varchar(300) NULL    
> LS_COLORS varchar(300) NULL    
> XNLSPATH  varchar(300) NULL    
> HOSTTYPE  varchar(300) NULL    
> CONFIG_SITE   varchar(300) NULL    
> FROM_HEADER   varchar(300) NULL    
> PAGER varchar(300) NULL    
> CSHEDIT   varchar(300) NULL    
> XDG_CONFIG_DIRS   varchar(300) NULL    
> LIBGL_DEBUG   varchar(300) NULL    
> MINICOM   varchar(300) NULL    
> MAIL  varchar(300) NULL    
> CPU   varchar(300) NULL    
> INPUTRC   varchar(300) NULL    
> PWD   varchar(300) NULL    
> LANG  varchar(300) NULL    
> PYTHONSTARTUP varchar(300) NULL    
> GPG_TTY   varchar(300) NULL    
> SHLVL varchar(300) NULL    
> HTTP_USER_AGENT_I bigint(20) NULL  
> SSH_CONNECTION    varchar(300) NULL    
> LESSCLOSE varchar(300) NULL    
> WINDOWMANAGER varchar(300) NULL    
> REDIRECT_spider   varchar(300) NULL    
> spider    varchar(300) NULL    
> CONTENT_TYPE  varchar(50) NULL     
> HTTP_REFERER  varchar(50) NULL     
> HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET   varchar(75) NULL     
> HTTP_DNT  varchar(10) NULL
> ```

Comment: How is that table used? How do you query the database? When you perform queries that use this table: Do you need all the values for all the columns? - As a general rule, when you don't know which kind of queries you're going to perform beforehand: just normalize. If your columns will have just a few distinct values, use `TINYINT` or `SMALLINT`. When you query  the database, *don't* make a `GET` for every lookup. Just use a `SELECT` with as many [`JOINs`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

"5-6 distinct values" -- `TINYINT UNSIGNED` or `ENUM`.

I lean toward `ENUM` if the options are unlikely to change over time.  An `ENUM NOT NULL` takes 1 byte (for up to 255 options).  Consider making the *first* enum option be "unspecified" (or whatever) instead of making `NULLable`.  Note:  I don't think you can have commas in a enum option; suggest you replace with some other char.

Consider dynamic normalization.  That is, when a string (such as "x-gzip, gzip, deflate") comes in, look it up in a table and find (or create) an id; then use that id as a `TINYINT UNSIGNED` or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` in the main table.  (If you choose this approach, we should discuss IODKU and "burning" of ids.)

Sparse data -- There are multiple options.

- `NULLable` columns: 1 bit per column *when `NULL`*.
- `JSON` -- this is open-ended, and rather compact if most of the possible columns are missing (and you don't mention them in the JSON).  I also like to compress (in the client) the json and put it into a `BLOB` -- this gives even more shrinkage (typically 3x).  Do not plan on using any thing from within the JSON in a `WHERE` clause.
- Separate table(s).  Let me fabricate an example:  Suppose some small percentage of rows have an image associated with them.  And the are 10 'columns' associated with each image.  Make a table of images with 11 columns, including an id back to the main table.  Then use `LEFT JOIN` when you need the image-related columns.

70 columns is a lot.  But not necessarily too many.

100K rows is probably less than 1GB, even without my suggestions.  Is that "too big"?

If this is a "log", will you be summarizing stuff like `COUNT(*)`, `SUM(...)`, etc over a day/week?  That is another topic to discuss.

**Specifics**

(Now seeing the column names...)

- Don't normalize "continuous" values, such as `TIMEs`;
- Things like `AGENT` work well in a lookup table.  You might want to use `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes; 64K max) instead of `TINYINT` just in case there is a lot of variety.  `HOST` might fit here, depending on your traffic.
- But... If a value is usually missing, it may be more efficient to put it into JSON -- bigger, but less frequent, than the always-present 2-byte `SMALLINT`.
- That many `VARCHAR(300)` may prevent you from using InnoDB, which you should use.  Switching to JSON for many of them will avoid this limit.

But...  Do you really need the data?  It seems like you only need a little bit of it for statistics; the rest could be simply written to a flat file, not a database.  That way, you get the stats easily accessible, and the raw data more compact and still accessible if you decide you missed something.  While you are at it, don't save one line per 'request', summarize the data for each, say, hour.  That will save more space and 'report' time.

Comment: Would a SET be helpful?  For 1. x-gzip  2. gzip 3. deflate and etc then just toggle on the combination you want.

Comment: Good point -- `SET` is probably a good idea for `"gzip,deflate,br"`.  Your example has about 6 options -> 6 bits -> (rounded up) 1 byte consumed.  Caution:  It will take some code to discover that a 'new' zipper has been invented and `ALTER` the definition to add the new option.

Comment: I have 7 rows which contain file paths some relative some absolute, I was thinking of combining into 1 lookup table.  Is this a good or bad idea?

Comment: Useful if some paths show up multiple times -- thereby saving overall disk space.

Comment: I added some more.

Comment: I have resized all the columns to a more reasonable size.  Except, the large block of varchar(300) at the bottom are the ones that are always NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Using lookup columns is definitely the way to go here.  For all except the columns that are always present.

Today I have 2x as much data nearly 100k records, and it only uses 54mb.  Storing all those null used over 100mb for less than 1/2 the records that I have now.

The lookup columns are integers so they only use 2 bytes each for each column.
Still researching further improvements.

Some I could probably shrink to TINYINT, I just don't know yet if it actually saves that many bytes.

Comment: Integers ([`INT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/int/)) are not two bytes, but four. [SMALLINT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/smallint/) is two bytes, though. Strange that your `NULL`s took up so much space.